# How do I find multiple instances of a element, based on it's class, in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to find how many instances of the same class(.rtmenu) are visible? Then target each individual?

Much Appreciated, Thanks

Comment: The documentation is an amazing thing!
http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what floyddotnet said.

and `$('.rtmenu:visible').length` if you still want to know how many of them there are.

**Edit in response to question in the comments -**

there are a bunch of ways to target a specific element, depends on exactly what you mean. You can loop through them all one by one with `each` (see the other answer). You can access the [indexor and element](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in `each` using the alternative signature:

```
$('.rtmenu:visible').each(function(index, elem) { ... });
```

you can use an [index selector](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) directly:

```
$('.rtmenu:visible').eq(1); // select the 2nd element (index is 0 based)
```

Or of course you could use a specific Id or multiple class selector if you really only want to find a specific element.

The jQuery documentation is pretty good, poke around in there and you can usually find something that does what you need, with good examples.

Comment: How would I target a specific one if there were 3 instances of '.rtmenu'? Sorry I'm a novice at Jquery/Javascript

Comment: @Nasir: not sure exactly what you mean, but updated the answer to give a few more pointers.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.rtmenu:visible').each(function(){
  //$(this) is the referenz to the DOM-Element.
});
```